# Finding the end of a Relationship chain optimally

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, recursive, query-performance

I have a table that contains an id column, a parent column, and it's child column. So for every record, I know what record comes before it and what will come after it in a chain relationship, but from the individual record, I don't know what position it is within the chain nor what the first part or last part of the chain.

For demonstration purposes, assume we have the following setup. I realize that there are many design issues with this type of setup, but this is what I have to work with.

```
CREATE TABLE Relationships (
ID VARCHAR(4), 
ParentID VARCHAR(4),
ChildID VARCHAR(4)
)

-- Insert root entries with their children
INSERT INTO Relationships (ID, ParentID, ChildID)
VALUES ('0001', '', '0003'), ('0002', '', '0004')

-- Now add further entries for each relationship chain
INSERT INTO Relationships(ID, ParentID, ChildID)
VALUES('0003', '0001', '0005'), ('0005', '0003', '0006'), ('0006', '0005', '0007'), ('0007', '0006', ''), 
  ('0004', '0002', '')

--Now we have two chains of 0001 -> 0003 -> 0005 -> 0006 -> 0007 and 0002 ->   0004
```

With a recursive CTE like below, I can find how all records are related in their chain and their position within the chain.

```
WITH RelationshipChain AS (
SELECT ID, ParentID, ChildID, 0 AS Seq, ID AS RootID
FROM Relationships WHERE ParentID = ''
UNION ALL
SELECT r2.ID, r2.ParentID, r2.ChildID, rc.Seq + 1 AS Seq, rc.RootID AS RootID
FROM Relationships r2 
INNER JOIN RelationshipChain rc ON rc.ChildID = r2.ID 
)

SELECT * FROM RelationshipChain
ORDER BY RootID, Seq
```

For about 2 million records this runs in about 30 seconds which is pretty good, however if I try to also include what the final part of the chain, it takes 4x as long to run. Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
WITH RelationshipChain AS (
SELECT ID, ParentID, ChildID, 0 AS Seq, ID AS RootID
FROM Relationships WHERE ParentID = ''
UNION ALL
SELECT r2.ID, r2.ParentID, r2.ChildID, rc.Seq + 1 AS Seq, rc.RootID AS RootID
FROM Relationships r2 
INNER JOIN RelationshipChain rc ON rc.ChildID = r2.ID 
)

SELECT * 
FROM RelationshipChain rc
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT MAX(Seq) AS FinalSeq FROM RelationshipChain WHERE rc.RootID = RootID
) AS b
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT ID AS LastChild FROM RelationshipChain WHERE b.FinalSeq = seq AND rc.RootID = RootID
) AS c
ORDER BY RootID, Seq
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your dataset, so can't test if this is better, but it *feels* better. After building the chains, we *reverse* them to find the 'childest' item in each chain, then join back to the original chain.

```
-- The same as your first CTE
;WITH RelationshipChain AS (
SELECT ID, ParentID, ChildID, 0 AS Seq, ID AS RootID
FROM Relationships WHERE ParentID = ''
UNION ALL
SELECT r2.ID, r2.ParentID, r2.ChildID, rc.Seq + 1 AS Seq, rc.RootID AS RootID
FROM Relationships r2 
INNER JOIN RelationshipChain rc ON rc.ChildID = r2.ID 
)

-- This CTE is new and reverses the sense of the chains
, BackChain AS (
SELECT ID, RootID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RootID ORDER BY Seq DESC) BackSeq
FROM RelationshipChain
)

-- Now we join each chain to the childest item in the reverse chain
SELECT 
    rc.ID
    , rc.ParentID
    , rc.ChildID
    , rc.Seq
    , rc.RootID
    , bc.ID ChainEndID
FROM RelationshipChain rc INNER JOIN BackChain bc ON RC.RootID = bc.RootID AND bc.BackSeq = 1
ORDER BY RootID, Seq
```

Results with your sample data:

```
ID   ParentID ChildID Seq         RootID ChainEndID
---- -------- ------- ----------- ------ ----------
0001          0003    0           0001   0007
0003 0001     0005    1           0001   0007
0005 0003     0006    2           0001   0007
0006 0005     0007    3           0001   0007
0007 0006             4           0001   0007
0002          0004    0           0002   0004
0004 0002             1           0002   0004
```

Indexes will help performance.